# How to always scale around a fixed point (center of the map)

Tags: android, mapbox, scaling, mapbox-android

I'm creating an application where the user can select a location ( like in this example : https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-picker/ ).

How to change the behavior of the `standardScaleGestureDetector` to make it always scale around a fixed point (like the center of the map) ?

I suppose that their is a relation with the focalPoint, but I don't know how to make it fixed.

I found a relative subject on github :
 https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/4151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide your own focal point with `mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setFocalPoint(customPoint)`, the map gesture detector will use this point instead of the center of the gesture.